# trying to use web3-utils but not working

Tags: solidity, web3js, hash

Trying to use web3-utils.

I installed the package via NPM , however, I am getting the error that sha3 is undefined..

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sha3' of undefined
    at C:\block2\deliver.js:12:28
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\block2\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\block2\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\block2\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\block2\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\block2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\block2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\block2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (C:\block2\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\block2\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

CODE:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
Web3 = require("web3");
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

var util = require('web3-utils');



app.get('/endpoint', function(request, response) {
    var id = request.query.id;
    response.end(web3.utils.sha3('test'));
});

app.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log('Listening to port:  ' + 3000);
});
```

Comment: What's your `web3.version`?  `web3.utils.sha3` is available in the latest 1.0.0-betas, but not in the "release" branch, 0.20.  Which version is installed by `npm` changed recently.  Best to check.

Comment: How can I check `web3`version? @benjaminion

Comment: @Alper type `web3.version` in the node console (after loading web3 as above).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please check your web3.js library version.

In versions < 1.0 you can call [`web3.sha3('test')`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3sha3).
In 1.0 it was moved to [`web3.utils.sha3`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#sha3)

Another option is to use `web3-utils` library, in this case you need to call `utils.sha3('test')`.

Comment: I cannot do `web3.utils.sha3(lengthSlot, {encoding: 'hex'})` or it just returns a different result from `web3.sha3(lengthSlot, {encoding: 'hex'})`

Answer (score 2):

Check your version by this call: `web3.version.api`
For versions before 1.x.x, use function from this [api](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3toascii).
there the example of correct code.`web3.toAscii`