# Web3: web3.utils is undefined

Tags: web3js, dapps, javascript, ethereum-classic

I am kinda new to Ethereum and Web3 so I am trying to implement the [Ethereum: Building Blockchain Decentralized Apps (DApps)](https://www.lynda.com/JavaScript-tutorials/Ethereum-Building-Blockchain-Decentralized-Apps-DApps/706935-2.html) tutorial. 
I have already installed web3 and web3-utils.

> `npm view web3 version` 
>   `1.0.0-beta.48`

My code is :

```
<script src="web3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>      
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
//checking   the version of web3
  if ((typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') || (typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined')){
      web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  } else{
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
  }
  var version = web3.version.api;
  console.log("Using web3 version: " + version);

//Form function
  $('#contract-form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var fromAddress = $('#fromAddress').val();

    //checking if the address of the uploader's is valid
    if(web3.utils.isAddress(fromAddress) != true) {
      alert('You did not enter a valid ethereum address.');
      return;
    }
  });
</script>
```

I get the error

> TypeError: web3.utils is undefined[Learn More

I actually upgraded my web3 version to 1.0.0 in case [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24218/trying-to-use-web3-utils-but-not-working) question's solution worked in my problem but nothing changed. 
Any help would be valuable , thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be problem with your web3.js file. Try replacing

```
<script src="web3.min.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.0.0-beta.34/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Happy to hear this from you